# How do I convert an array of strings to a array of unique values?

Tags: java, arrays

In Java, how do I convert an array of strings to a array of unique values?

If I have this array of Strings:

```
String[] test = {"1","1","1","2"}
```

And I want to end up with:

```
String[] uq = {"1","2"}
```

Comment: Use modified Mergesort, removing duplicates when encountered, instead of adding both copies back to the list. Runs in **`O(N*logN)`**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're going with the `HashSet`-approach (which seems pretty handy) you should use a `LinkedHashSet` instead of a `HashSet` if you want to maintain the array's order!

```
Set<String> temp = new LinkedHashSet<String>( Arrays.asList( array ) );
String[] result = temp.toArray( new String[temp.size()] );
```

Answer (score 14):

Quick but somewhat inefficient way would be:

```
Set<String> temp = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(test));
String[] uq = temp.toArray(new String[temp.size()]);
```

Comment: Why is it inefficient? Considering the array probably has more than four values. The alternative is to sort the array and look for dupes, right?

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] test = {"1","1","1","2"};
java.util.Set result = new java.util.HashSet(java.util.Arrays.asList(test));
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: The ""+ part is not required, System.out.println(result) is all that's needed.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the HashSet approach would be to:

1. Sort the input array
2. Count the number of non-duplicate values in the sorted array
3. Allocate the output array
4. Iterate over the sorted array, copying the non-duplicate values to it.

The HashSet approach is `O(N)` on average assuming that 1) you preallocate the HashSet with the right size and 2) the (non-duplicate) values in the input array hash roughly evenly.  (But if the value hashing is pathological, the worst case is `O(N**2)` !)

The sorting approach is `O(NlogN)` on average.

The HashSet approach takes more memory on average.

If you are doing this infrequently **OR** for really large "well behaved" input arrays, the HashSet approach is probably better.  Otherwise, it could be a toss-up which approach is better.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the answers on this page and none worked as-is.  So, here is how I solved it, inspired by the answers from **Taig** and **akuhn** :

```
import groovy.io.*;
def arr = ["5", "5", "7", "6", "7", "8", "0"]
List<String> uniqueList = new ArrayList<String>( 
         new LinkedHashSet<String>( arr.asList() ).sort() );
System.out.println( uniqueList )
```

Answer (score 2):

Just found a nicer way in Java 8 :

```
Arrays.stream(aList).distinct().toArray(String[]::new)
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to create a set, add each element in the array to it, and then convert the set to an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
List list = Arrays.asList(test);
Set set = new HashSet(list);

String[] uq = set.toArray();
```

Comment: It would be easier to call `Set.toArray()`.

Comment: Yeah for a moment I choose the loooong way dunno why

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution:

```
int[] A = {2, 1, 2, 0, 1};

Arrays.sort(A);

ArrayList<Integer> B = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
 if (i == A.length-1) {
    B.add(A[i]);
 }
 else if (A[i] != A[i+1]) {
    B.add(A[i]);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] getDistinctElementsArray(String[] arr){

    StringBuilder distStrings = new StringBuilder();
    distStrings.append(arr[0] + " ");
    for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
        if( arr[i].equals(arr[i-1])){}
        else{
            distStrings.append(arr[i] + " ");
        }
    }
    return distStrings.toString().split(" ");
}
```